# Disable click event on marker in mapbox

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am creating a poi create task with mapbox map, The marker should move to the new position if the click event is occurring on map. The marker will initially be placed on the map at a default position. I want to disable the click event when it is clicking on the marker, It is working fine for the initial marker( `clickable: false`) option, For the dynamically added markers this option is not working

```
tMarker = L.marker(
        new (L.LatLng)(latitude,longitude),{
          clickable: false
        }
      )
```

Comment: Any code for the part where markers are added dynamically ?

Comment: Sorry this happens for all the markers, Disabling Clickable is not preventing click event on the marker

Comment: So even the initial marker ?

Comment: `Marker = L.marker(
    new (L.LatLng)(latitude, longitude),
  ).on('click', preventMarkerEvent)` I have  added event listener to listen the click event  and  added `preventMarkerEvent = ->
  e.preventDefault()`, This works fine

Comment: Please specify your Leaflet version.

Comment: I am using  mapbox.js v3.1.1 and referred this link  [https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.1/l-marker